# Vue local config file per App installation

Tags: vuejs2

I am new the Vue.js and I am trying first steps with an app. So for understanding the basics, I want a local config file per App installation to customise some needed variables in the code.

So in my main.js I tried the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

let config;

try {
  config = require('../config.json');
} catch (e) {
  config = require('../public/config.json');
}

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.prototype.$localConfig = config;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

This is working, until I build the production version with the dist folder. If I open the config.json in the root of the dist and change a property value, I see always the first defined values from the development env. So is webpack making there some caching? Is this at all the right way of handling such a local config file per App installation?

Maybe someone could give me some tips on this.

Comment: The easiest and fastest way for now is to include an config.js in the index.html Template file of the app und load it this way - Vue.prototype.$config = window.APPCONFIG; - maybe not the best option, but working as expected. Maybe someone have a better way for handling this ...

Answer (score 1):

Doing `config = require('../config.json');` is the same as `import config from "../config.json"` in a way that it takes the content of your `json` file **at build time**, transform it into JS object and make's it part of your app bundle.

You can do what you propose in a comment (include the file in a `script` tag in your `index.html`) but that means your app is doing additional request to the server to load the config and by doing so increasing "time to render" (time user have to wait until the page is fully rendered)

Most common way to handle app configuration in Vue/Webpack world is by using  [Environment Variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables) - those also "work" at build time tho so you need to build your app separately for each environment

Answer (score 0):

```
let config
const configPromise =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? import('../config.json')
    : import('../public/config.json')
configPromise.then(res => {
  config = res.default
})
```